# como faço para aplicar o renderer2 no angular?

Tags: angular

Pelo que entendi não dá pra usar o server-side rendering e manipular diretamente os
elementos nativos, como faço para usar o renderer2?

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, HostBinding, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

import $ from 'jquery';
import 'owl.carousel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-owl-carousel',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class OwlCarouselComponent implements OnInit {

  @HostBinding('class') defaultClass = 'owl-carousel';
  @Input() options: object;

  $owlElement: any;
  defaultOptions: any = {};

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2 ) { }

  ngOnInit(){}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.$owlElement = $(this.el.nativeElement).owlCarousel(this.defaultOptions);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.$owlElement.owlCarousel('destroy');
    this.$owlElement = null;
  }

}
```

Comment: Nossa, estou tendo o mesmo B.O. Vc conseguiu resolver isso?